# Jquery Mobile Responsive Grid with variable row/column sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I am trying to create a dashboard in my jQuery Mobile application.  The dashboard page will contain a map in upper left corner.  Around the map will be various charts and tables.

The charts are always going to be 400px by 400px.  Tables will always be 400px wide and may be greater than 400px tall.

I'm no CSS guru, but I'm looking to create a responsive layout so that the map will always take up at least half the width of the page.  If 2 charts/tables can fit side by side in half the page then they will be and the map width should fill the rest of the width of the page.  Similarly, if 2 charts can fit vertically within the full height of the page, then hey will and the map will be made the height of 2 charts stacked vertically (including the gap between them).  Then any additional charts will be added below the map side by side until the page width is full.  Then new rows of charts will be added.

Here are some wireframes to demonstrate:

Landscape:
[image: Wireframe1]

Portrait:
[image: Wireframe2]

Can anyone recommend a way to do this using an existing framework or plugin?  I started writing my own Javascript to rearrange the charts when the window is resized or orientation is changed, but it got very complicated very quickly.  I know there's got to be something out there already.

Would the responsive grid framework within jQuery Mobile accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

yea you should look into bootstrap grids or skeleton or one of those.  basically in bootstrap it would be something like

```
<div id="map" class="col-md-6 col-sm-8"></div>
<div id="chart1" class="col-md-3 col-sm-4"></div>
<div id="chart2" class="col-md-3 col-sm-4"></div>
<div id="chart3" class="col-md-3 col-sm-4"></div>
```

(etc...for the rest of the charts)